# Executing SQL code on the server using DataContext rejects GO statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to deploy my database on customers SQL Server instances automatically. 
I have my database generation script and it can be executed on a SQL Server instance without any problem.

Consider this simplified version of the SQL code

```
CREATE DATABASE [DataMining]
Go

// Some Table Creation Code

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResetDatabase]
AS
BEGIN
delete from dbo.Result;
END

GO
```

Putting this code in a string and passing it to

```
myDataContext.ExecuteCommand(query);
```

will throw an exception with this message

> Incorrect syntax near 'Go'.

It will go away if I just remove the Go statements but that's not possible as "Create Procedure" should be the first statement in a query batch.
One solution is to break my query in to multiple queries but my database contains about 10 tables and 8 procedures and 4 types. Putting them in separate queries makes the code not so neat.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `GO` is used by SSMS to separate batches. It is not a TSQL statement.

Comment: Suggestion: don't include the `GO` as part of `query`. As @HABO said, `GO` is not T-SQL.

Comment: Ok, I will split the query at every GO statement into a new query. Thanks.